# Why are all my motors and transformers failing at this specific location?

Tags: motor, transformer, amperage, three-phase

At my job there is a vacuum oven.

There is a 50 hp, enclosed cooling fan. that circulates N2 gas upon quench, the design of the unit runs 480 volts through a reduction transformer to 230 volts. This runs the 50 hp motor at 230 volts (when it burned out).

The motor was replaced with a good motor, the transformer has been tested to be good also.

The 480 volt building power is running many motors without issue. However when the transformer is hooked up to the 480 power to run the motor at 230 volts the motor free spins at 470 amps per leg. 200 volt draw down.

The 480 volts input power goes to 457 volts and the amps per leg is 244 amps on two legs and 222 on the third. the motor and transformer has been tested run at a different location to run at less the 10 amps free spin per leg..normal.

On that motor. if the motor is not hooked up to the transformer it has a normal 235 volt output. three pole output no draw as normal.

if any 3 ph. motor is hooked up. has the same issue very high amp draw for no reason.

(2) transformers were put to the same test both did the same high amp draw on any motor hooked up.

What would cause this issue?

From the input building power from the street is 600 amp at 3ph wye, three pole transformers.

If a motor is hooked up without running through a reduction transformer it runs fine. Running through a transformer it goes to hell. Only in this location!?

I have never seen this before 480 building power seem fine if it goes through a 3 ph transformer to run a motor there is a very high draw on the motor a free run 5 hp. ran at 109 amps. (very loud buss noise). hook up without a transformer run at 3 amps. fine. is it magic 3ph in should be 3 ph out on a transformer from street power. not so at this location.

This is very abnormal. I have no answer.

EDIT: 7/8/19
Project has been put on hold, no longer working on it. No answer though, still something unique and strange about this situation. Thank you all for contributing this will always be stuck in my head as time goes on, but i cant do anything about it now.

Comment: Sounds like the transformer is the common link - are you sure that its output windings are correctly configured for star or delta and somehow not screwed up by some incompetent dude?

Comment: Rated current at full load should be ~60A so 470A no load is an oxymoron with saturated cores or ? stuck starter winding

Comment: I took the liberty of deleting specific company name information. You may not like the job, but, stating it clearly online with other related comments may do you a major disservice. Add it back in if you really want to get fired and possibly worse :-) . :-(. | I strongly suggest that you construct sentences correctly - as you are obviously capable of doing. This is NOT me being picky/precious but advice based on the impression people tend to form and resultant responsiveness. [I didn't program their brains :-) .]

Comment: It strongly sounds as though the actual voltage is higher than believed. Have voltages been measured at the motor? From the figures provided it SOUNDS as though you have made actual measurements, but all indications are of grossly excessive voltage.

Comment: Check the starter and see if it has a bad leg?

Comment: Why use transformers for big 240v motors? 480v motors would be more efficient. Existing may be rewound at much lower cost than new, then the transformers recycled. Any industrial motor repair shop could give a quote, such as whelco.com or industrialmotorservice.com, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I'm puzzled as to why you would run a 50HP motor at 240V when you have 480V available. Most motors that large will be capable of being connected either way. That transformer is not doing you any favors, even if it is working correctly.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thank you for removing that.

Comment: I find this hard to understand.  So at 230V and low of 222A, assuming a pf of 0.8, gives you  70.8kW, which is 95hp from a 50hp motor.  No wonder it fails.  Let alone **470 amps per leg**.  Please reread your question, because your use of V and A without clearly stating primary/secondary side is confusing.  You do need some form of schematic.  And **it burned out**.  The motor or the transformer.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat the motor burned out.

Comment: You have too much information without specifics.  It is hard to troubleshoot running problems when you are doing the measurements.  You need to clean up your question.  Having said that.  All motors fail due to heat.  The motor and transformer work at another location.  At failing location.  Disconnect all wires (at box physically pull breaker).  Megger all disconnected wires to each other and ground.  Check cooling fan spins freely.  If you are consuming 95hp from a 50hp motor, the problem is on fan side.  My best advice is to hire a qualified electrician.  Odds are wires are compromised

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat the project has stopped. They chose to run everything 480V even though problem still exists, They still have whatever from the street power has caused the problem still coming into the plant. But they do not want to find out what it is.

all is good! less work for me! :)